# Why does this query require a parameter?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following SQL query in MS Access.  I'm trying to order the output by the results of an expression contained in the column labeled as 'Response'.  My problem is that when I run the query Access prompts me to enter a parameter value for Response.  I tried entering zero and one to see what would happen.  The query runs in those cases but the sort order is wrong.  Can someone please explain to me why this query would require a parameter? Am I doing something wrong?

```
SELECT Market,
       Sum(Calls) AS SumOfCalls,
       Sum([A25-54 IMPs] * 1000) AS Impressions,
       Round(SumOfCalls/Impressions, 6) AS Response
FROM DRTV_CentralOnly
WHERE [Creative]<>'#N/A'
GROUP BY Market
ORDER BY Response Desc;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not requiring a parameter. The problem is that you are using columns aliases in one your `Response` column.  You need to use the actual calculations instead.

```
SELECT Market
    , Sum(Calls) AS SumOfCalls
    , Sum([A25-54 IMPs] * 1000) AS Impressions
    , Round(Sum(Calls)/Sum([A25-54 IMPs] * 1000), 6) AS Response
FROM DRTV_CentralOnly
WHERE [Creative]<>'#N/A'
GROUP BY Market
ORDER BY 4 Desc;
```

Comment: @Andomar that's correct.  I ran the query both ways to verify.  Thanks to you both.

Comment: +1 I would change the sort expression, though: `ORDER BY 4 DESC`

Comment: @HansUp nice catch, I agree and changed it.  Much cleaner.

Comment: @bluefeet: you've misunderstood the problem and hit upon the fix by accident! See my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

@bluefeet said:

> The problem is that you are using columns aliases in one your Response column.

Actually, that is not the problem at all. MS Access does indeed allow `AS` clauses ("columns aliases") to be used in the way the OP has used them.

Rather, the problem is that MS Access does not allow `AS` clauses in the `ORDER BY` clause.

It is altering the `ORDER BY` clause to use an ordinal position that fixes the query. The changes to the `SELECT` clause are a red herring!

The following should work:

```
SELECT Market,
       Sum(Calls) AS SumOfCalls,
       Sum([A25-54 IMPs] * 1000) AS Impressions,
       Round(SumOfCalls/Impressions, 6) AS Response
FROM DRTV_CentralOnly
WHERE [Creative]<>'#N/A'
GROUP BY Market
ORDER BY 4 Desc;
```