# Query with switch function requests parameter value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Background: Excel worksheet as front end to an Access database.  Excel contains VBA code and uses ADODB to move values into and out of the tables in Access.

One column is a composite value which describes a complex priority relationship.  One digit for priority level (1-6), one letter for more granular level (A-C), and a type of project (Safety, Security, Enviro, etc.)  The values look like "2B - Maint.", "2A - ProcCntl"

I need to sort the results of a select * query in different ways.  Sometimes with the typical Alpha sort which would list 1A values before 1B before 4C.  Other times I need to sort all the Safety as a group, Maint. as another, etc. A simple alpha sort on the project type doesn't work because the manager wants a specific order.

I am using the Switch function to assign the order.  I have found a couple of ways to make this work in Access but they all ask for a parameter value when I run the query. Entering a blank value gets the desired result.  Moving the query into the VBA of Excel returns an error complaining of an empty parameter.

Here is one of the "working" queries:

> SELECT *, Mid([Priority],6,2) AS ProjClass,
>   Switch(ProjClass="Sa",1,ProjClass="En",2,ProjClass="Se",3,ProjClass="6S",4,ProjClass="Qu",5,ProjClass="Pr",6,ProjClass="Ma",7,ProjClass="Bu",8)
>   AS [FirstSort]
>
> FROM tblProjects
>
> ORDER BY [FirstSort] ASC, [Priority] ASC;

When I run this through the VBA I get

> Run-time error "No value given for one or more required parameters."

When I run it in Access a "Enter Parameter Value" dialog opens asking for FirstSort. I click through and see the result is correctly sorted.

The root question: Why is Access seeing FirstSort as a parameter and not a field name?

I think I need to understand that before I can fix the VBA issue.

Comment: Your ORDER BY has to have the calc all over again... `ORDER BY Mid([Priority],6,2) AS ProjClass, Switch(ProjClass="Sa",1,ProjClass="En",2,ProjClass="Se",3,ProjClass="6S",4,ProjClass="Qu",5,ProjClass="Pr",6,ProjClass="Ma",7,ProjClass="Bu",8)`

Comment: BraX: I tried that but got errors.  I forget the specific error but I spent an hour or so before moving on.   I think that it also asked for the parameter on ProjClass, which would make sense with the new understanding since ProjClass is itself an alias.  But I also tried putting the Mid function in place of the ProjClass ref (really messy!)  but Access and VBA seem not to like the function in the Order By clause either.

Answer (score 0):

More research has revealed yet another Access quirk:  The problem is that MS Access does not allow AS clauses in the ORDER BY clause.

So a little experimentation lead me to change the ORDER BY clause to ORDER BY 3 ASC, [Priority] ASC;

I chose the three because it is the third field expression in the query.  It works but it would be great if someone could clarify the specific rule that makes it work.

Hat tip: [Why does this query require a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705176/why-does-this-query-require-a-parameter?rq=1)  and onedaywhen's answer.

Comment: It's not the third field expression in the query. Your query starts with SELECT *. SELECT * will select all columns from the underlying query. Ditch the asterisk (and the comma that proceeds the asterisk).

Comment: Rene: I wondered about that count.  If I ditch the asterisk, I need to name all 20-some columns--no thanks.   I have since built other queries on this model and as long as the ordinal matches the position in the Select section it works.  I have one query that sorts on three different expressions in the Select, all following the asterisk.  Example: Order BY 2 DESC, 3 ASC, 4 DESC;     and it works as expected.   It may not be right, but it works. And that does bother me. I would love to know what right IS, not just what works.

Answer (score 0):

ProjClass is a field created during execution of the query. Before that when the SQL engine is determining an execution plan for the query it will not recognize that field name so assumes it is parameter. SORT is done at the end of the query and by that time the engine knows which is the third field.

An alternative is to create another table called something like tblPriority with 2 columns ProjectClass and SortOrder

```
ProjClass   SortOrder
Sa          1
En          2
Se          3
6S          4
Qu          5
Pr          6
Ma          7
Bu          8
```

and use a JOIN

```
SELECT A.* FROM tblProjects AS A
LEFT JOIN tblPriority as B 
     ON B.ProjClass = Mid(A.Priority,6,2)
ORDER BY SortOrder
```

Comment: CDP1802:  I have thought about your solution. I like it.  But I fear that two of the similar queries I need to do require using parts of another field (a MID and  RIGHT--Think of structured invoice numbers where part represents a branch office, another part the fiscal year, and finally a sequential component. And accounting decides the format and IT has to work with it…)   I think a join on 3 different tables to build the ORDER BY clause would be more confusing.  But, I do like this approach!